# CakePHP- saving multiple records of t he same model, within same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have quite an odd problem which i can't seem to figure out. I read some related questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134085/cakephp-how-to-update-multiple-records-at-the-same-time-with-the-form-helper)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332329/how-can-i-create-multiple-forms-on-a-single-page-in-cakephp).  However, these both use normal submission, whereas I am performing the save through an ajax request. (Which brings me to my problem).

Firstly, I am not sure how much level of 'graceful' degradation needs to be implemented nowadays with js/ajax (can easily not use a form).. However for the sake of js-disabled browsers/users, I think its' wise to use a form. What's your intake on this?

The main question however is the one below. 
I am trying to edit records using ajax as follows:

This is my form :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('BloodTarget',array('type' => 'post', 'default'=> false));?>
<?php $i = 0;?>

<?php foreach($targets as $target):?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input("BloodTarget.$i.cur_amount", array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $target['BloodTarget']['target_amount']));?>        
<?php echo $this->Form->input("BloodTarget.$i.id", array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $target['BloodTarget']['id']));?>                                                                                        
<?php echo $this->Form->input("BloodTarget.$i.target_amount",array('label' => false,'type' => 'number','value' => $target['BloodTarget']['target_amount']));?>

<?php $i++;?>
<?php endforeach;?>


<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

This generates something like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[BloodTarget][0][cur_amount]" value="26" id="BloodTarget0CurAmount">
<input type="hidden" name="data[BloodTarget][0][id]" value="1" id="BloodTarget0Id">
<div class="input number"><input name="data[BloodTarget][0][target_amount]" value="26"
 type="number" id="BloodTarget0TargetAmount"></div>
```

In my jquery's ajax function I serialize the form

`data: $("#BloodTargetRequestBloodForm").serializeArray()`

which sends data like so:

```
_method:POST
data[BloodTarget][blood_group_id]:1
data[BloodTarget][blood_component]:Whole Blood
data[BloodTarget][target_amount]:0
```

Finally I save the data from the controller 
`if($this->BloodTarget->save($this->request->data['BloodTarget']))`

and it does save, however, it creates a new record with an ID of zero instead updating the 3 records within the form.

What is wrong here? I also tried to set the ID before update,(but this doesn't work)

`$this->BloodTarget->id = $this->request->data['BloodTarget']['id'];`

For the life of me, can anyone please identify what is wrong in my code? What am I missing? 
Thanks a heaps!

Answer (score 0):

Bloody stuff mate ;)

Maybe I am stupid but i think this rule:

```
data[BloodTarget][blood_group_id]:1 // see blood_group_id
```

is not the same as

```
$this->BloodTarget->id = $this->request->data['BloodTarget']['id']; // see id
```

So maybe you should rename

```
data[BloodTarget][blood_group_id]:1
```

to:

```
data[BloodTarget][id]:1
```

Good luck!